# Printing the names of highest scorers from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, for-loop, tuples

If I open a text file that includes names of people and their scores, how can I print BOTH names if there are 2 people that both scored the highest. Right now it only prints one of the names, and I would like it to print both, everything else works okay. Thanks in advance!!

Here is my code as of now:

```
maxName = ''
maxScore = 0
for line in file:
    i = line.strip().split()
    x = [int(y) for y in i[1:]]
    #print(z[0]," made ","$",sum(x))
    if sum(x) >= maxScore:
        maxName  = z[0]
        maxScore = sum(x)
print(f'The max total score is {maxScore}')       
print(f'those who scored the highest: {maxName}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It prints only one because you keep track of only one. To print more than one, keep track of them all in a list.

```
maxNames = []  # Keep names in this list
maxScore = 0
for line in file:
    i = line.strip().split()
    x = [int(y) for y in i[1:]]
    
    #### Only calculate the sum once
    totalScore = sum(x)

    if totalScore > maxScore: # If greater, create a new list containing only this name
        maxNames  = [i[0]]
        maxScore = totalScore
    elif totalScore == maxScore: # If equal, append this name to the list
        maxNames.append(i[0])


print(f'The max total score is {maxScore}')       
print(f'those who scored the highest: {maxNames}')
```

To print the items in the list *without* the accompanying brackets and separators, you can [`str.join()` the elements in the list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp)

```
printNames = ",".join(maxNames)
print(f'those who scored the highest: {printNames}')
```

Answer (score 2):

Store them in a list.  I changed `i` to `z` for you.

```
maxName = []
maxScore = 0
for line in file:
    z = line.strip().split()
    x = [int(y) for y in z[1:]]
    #print(z[0]," made ","$",sum(x))
    if sum(x) > maxScore:
        maxName  = [z[0]]
        maxScore = sum(x)
    elif sum(x) == maxScore:
        maxName.append( z[0] )
print(f'The max total score is {maxScore}')       
print(f'those who scored the highest: {maxName}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first find the maximum score, and then all the people who have this score:

```
lines = [i.strip('\n').split() for i in file]
max_score = max([sum(b) for _, *b in lines])
has_max = [a for a, *b in lines if sum(b) == max_score]
```